# Add 1 to rows meeting certian complex criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have several tables that I join into one table which looks like this:

```
Date                         Amount        pKey    kID    Source
10/4/2017 11:00:01 AM        49.34         27      81     TT
10/4/2017 10:49:29 AM        23.11         26      89     TT
10/4/2017 11:45:20 AM        54.14         24      42     G
10/4/2017  2:20:10 PM        10.20         26      89     G
```

Data comes into the source tables at different times each day. What I want to do is create a procedure or something that will "move" certain rows. If a TT row comes in AFTER the last G row of the day, I want to move the TT row to the next day (but only when it has the same pKey and kID as the last G row). So in the above case I want to take row number 4, and reset the Date to 10/5/2017 XX:XX:XX because it came in AFTER row number 2 - which has the same pKey and kID.

I realize "last" and "after" are relative constructs, but hopefully it all makes sense.

How can I accomplish this goal. Note that the [Date] comes in as a string so conversion will probably be required.

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
update t
    set date = dateadd(day, 1, date)
    where t.source = 'TT' and
          t.date < (select max(t2.date)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.pkey = t.pkey and t2.kid = t.kid and
                          t2.source = 'G' and
                          cast(t.date as date) = cast(t2.date as date)
                   );
```

It is pretty much a direct translation of your logic.

Comment: I think there might be an issue with the aliasing. I replaced the "t"'s with my table name dbo.Volumes and it ran, but there were no rows affected and I know there are several rows that meet the criteria. I tried running the select statement in the where clause and it says the t.pkey, t.kid, and t.date columns could not be bound...(which is suppose is expected) are you sure that aliasing is correct?

Comment: Update: Ahh, ran a select statement using the where clause and it came up with no rows, looks like I need to do some investigating on my end. Perhaps I explained the criteria wrong